# Symbolic constant example in Kernighan and Ritchie book

Tags: c, compiler-errors, symbolic-math, kernighan-and-ritchie

I copied the script example about symbolic constant of the book *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie 1988 p.15 as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOWER 0    /* lower limit of table */
#define UPPER 300  /* upper limit */
#define STEP 20    /* step size*/

/* print Fahrenheit-Celsius table */

main()
{
    int fahr;

    for (fahr = LOWER; fahr <= UPPER; fahr = fahr + STEP)
        printf("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32));
}
```

However when I run `gcc script.c` I get:

```
fahr_symbolic.c:9:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
1 warning generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? You spelled the `UPPER` macro as `UPER`. Pretty obvious by the warning. You have 2 different definitions of `LOWER`, I expect the second definition to actually be `STEP`.

Comment: Also, in C99 and above - function definitions should explicitly mention their return type. Don't rely on the implicit `int`.

Comment: well....your edit completely changed the question now - and it kinda serves no purpose anymore since there literally aren't really any issues.

Comment: @Chase. Sorry for the typos. I corrected it, still get a warning. What do you mean implicit `int`? Are you talking about `UPPER`, `LOWER` and `STEP`. Because that was precisely what I could not understand: there are those three variables defined without defining a type and I was wondering how it is possible

Comment: When you declare a function or variable without a specific type, it defaults to `int` implicitly. This is illegal since C99 and should no longer be used. I was not referring to the macros. Macros are defined using `#define` - their usage and definition should be very clearly described by any half decent C book and/or easily searchable [online reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). Note that macros do not need a return type since they are not real variables, they get replaced during the preprocessing stage.

Comment: Ok. As I prefer a book rather than online references, do you have any recommendation?

Comment: It should almost certainly be already explained in the c programming language book - though I cannot confirm this.

Comment: [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) is probably the most up to date book. Available for free as pdf too, or you can buy a printed book from that link. It's not really a beginner-friendly book but then neither is K&R.

Comment: Well i am at the beginning of the book which was written in 1988 and you are talking about C99 that s why I am asking. Tell me if you think it s still worth reading

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are reading a completely outdated and incorrect book.

- In the pre-standard C that the book was written for, you could just write anything because there was no standard. For example `main()` without a return type or skip `return 0;` at the end.
- In the first C standard from 1989 that the book was never correctly updated to<sup>1)</sup>, you could write `main()` without a return type but you would *had* to write `return 0;` at the end, otherwise the program invokes undefined behavior when the caller (the OS) uses the return value.
- In the updated C standard from 1999, "implicit int" `main()` was removed from the language and you have to write `int main (void)`. However, in this version of the language you can skip `return 0` in main(), which you couldn't do before.

The current C language from 2018 behaves identically to the version from 1999 in this regard. But the code in K&R has never been valid for any version of standardized C.

---

<sup>1)</sup> From appendix A.1 of K&R 2nd edition "This manual describes the C language specified by the draft submitted to ANSI on 31 October, 1988, for approval as 'American Standard for Information Systems - programming Language C, X3.159-1989.'"

Comment: @EricPostpischil The 2nd edition claims to be updated to C90. But `main() {}` without `return 0;` was always undefined behavior in C90. So how exactly is it not incorrect?

Comment: @EricPostpischil K&R 1st edition was published in 1978 for pre-standard C.

Comment: The 2nd edition from 1988 claims this in appendix A.1 "This manual describes the C language specified by the draft submitted to ANSI on 31 October, 1988, for approval as `American Standard for Information Systems - programming Language C, X3.159-1989.'' The manual is an interpretation of the proposed standard, not the standard itself, although care has been taken to make it a reliable guide to the language."  There were no changes in return type behavior between the X3.159 draft and C89. I'm pretty sure there weren't many changes overall from the draft and ANSI C89.

Comment: Also, I'm deadly tired of K&R huggers who respond to factual arguments why something in this book was always wrong even back in the days with "no it is a great book" and providing no arguments. If had lots of factual and typo errors even back in 1988. Bell Labs had a big errata for the book somewhere but it seems to have disappeared from the Internet.

Comment: You are correct, I had the version wrong and will retract my vote if an edit is made. However I still disagree with the vehemence you express at K&R; it is no more appropriate than the “hugging” you disapprove of. Judging the hard and long work of decades ago by modern standards is inappropriate. Would you have done any better back then? Under the same workload? With the same goals and time constraints? You could not copy text from the book and paste it into a source file for testing. Even if you could, likely the compiler they were using at the time would accept it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added K&R version quote to the answer. But my opinion that this book has been very harmful over the years remains. I wouldn't mix together Dennis Ritchie's work of inventing C with the work of writing this book. They really could have put in lots more work proof-reading of the 2nd edition.